# How to fix runtime error in netbeans of Gui with search option?

Tags: user-interface, compiler-errors, runtime-error, netbeans-8

I am creating a gui where I will take some info of people and store/append it in a file.
Then I created a textarea1 where i will show/display the stored info by name.
Lastly, I created a search option where when I input either name or phone number, I should get matched results shown/displayed in the other textarea2 below.
However, My gui is giving error and won't run at all eversince I wrote the code for the search option, which is button3 in the code. How can I fix it? btw, I'm using java frame form so, that is why the code is a lil lenthy.

````
package address.book;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class Students {
   private String name;
   private String phoneNo;
   private String email;
   private String streetAddress;

    public Students(String name, String phoneNo, String email, String streetAddress) {
        this.name = name;
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
        this.email = email;
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhoneNo() {
        return phoneNo;
    }

    public void setPhoneNo(String phoneNo) {
        this.phoneNo = phoneNo;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getStreetAddress() {
        return streetAddress;
    }

    public void setStreetAddress(String streetAddress) {
        this.streetAddress = streetAddress;
    }
   

}
    
    
    
public class AddressBook extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    private Object jTextArea2;
    private JLabel jLabel7;
    private JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private JTextField jTextField1;
    private JTextField jTextField2;
    private JTextField jTextField3;
    private JTextField jTextField4;
    private JTextField jTextField5;
    private JTextField jTextField6;

    /**
     * Creates new form AddressBook
     */
    public AddressBook() {
        initComponents();
        this.setTitle("Address Book");
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField4 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jTextField5 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField6 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jScrollPane2 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea2 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel7 = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel1.setText("Name :");

        jLabel2.setText("Phone No# :");

        jLabel3.setText("Email :");

        jLabel4.setText("Street Address :");

        jButton1.setText("Register");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jButton2.setText("Show");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel5.setText("Name :");

        jTextField6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jLabel6.setText("Phone No# :");

        jButton3.setText("Search");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextArea2.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea2.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane2.setViewportView(jTextArea2);

        jLabel7.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Courier New", 3, 18)); // NOI18N
        jLabel7.setText(" <Search a person by their name or phone number>");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(182, 182, 182)
                        .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 208, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(39, 39, 39)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane2)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel4)
                                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                .addGap(2, 2, 2)
                                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                                    .addComponent(jLabel1)
                                                    .addComponent(jLabel3))))
                                        .addGap(42, 42, 42)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 232, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                                .addComponent(jTextField1)
                                                .addComponent(jTextField2)
                                                .addComponent(jTextField3)
                                                .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 367, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                                        .addGap(56, 56, 56)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 355, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addComponent(jLabel5)
                                        .addGap(81, 81, 81)
                                        .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 355, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))))
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(30, 30, 30)
                        .addComponent(jLabel7))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(181, 181, 181)
                        .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 209, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(96, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton1)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 237, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jButton2)
                .addGap(29, 29, 29)
                .addComponent(jLabel7)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel5))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel6)
                    .addComponent(jTextField6, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                .addGap(20, 20, 20)
                .addComponent(jButton3)
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 203, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        String name = jTextField1.getText();
        String phoneNo = jTextField2.getText();
        String email = jTextField3.getText();
        String streetAddress = jTextField4.getText();
        try{
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Registration.txt", true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            
            pw.println(name+" "+phoneNo+" "+email+" "+streetAddress+" ");
            
           
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
              try{
            File f = new File("Registration.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            jTextArea1.setText("");
            while(sc.hasNext()){
               String name = sc.next();
               String phoneNo = sc.next();
               String email = sc.next();
               String streetAddress = sc.nextLine();
               String data = "Name: "+name+"\n "+"   PhoneNo: "+phoneNo+"\n "+"   Email: "+email+"\n "+"   StreetAddress: "+streetAddress+"\n\n";
               jTextArea1.append(data);
            }
            sc.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }                                        

    private void jTextField5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jTextField6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }                                           

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
                         try{
            File f = new File("Registration.txt");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(f);
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("Registration.txt", true);
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            jTextArea2.append("");
         
            Students [] students = new Students[10];
            int index = 0;
            while(sc.hasNext()){
             
                String namex = jTextField5.getText();
                String phoneNox = jTextField6.getText();
                
                String name = sc.next();
                String phoneNo = sc.next();
                String email = sc.next();
                String streetAddress = sc.next();
                 
                if(namex.equals(name)||phoneNox.equals(phoneNo)){
                Students st = new Students(name, phoneNo, email, streetAddress);
                students[index] = st;
                }
               
                index++;
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < index; i++){
                Students st = students[i];
                String data = "Results:\n\nName: "+st.getName()+"\n "+"   PhoneNo: "+st.getPhoneNo()+"\n "+"   Email: "+st.getEmail()+"\n "+"   StreetAddress: "+st.getStreetAddress()+"\n\n";
                jTextArea2.append(data);
            }
                    
            sc.close();
            pw.close();
        }
        catch(IOException e){
         e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
                
        
        
        
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AddressBook.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new AddressBook().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel7;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane2;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField5;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField6;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

also I tried to run it with a new code for button 3 and without the students class:
it still didn't work as planned. WHen I run it they say that the public main class is not in the package address book and the private labels all of the red in the code.

```
try{
   File f = new File("Registration");
   Scanner sc = new Scanner(f); 
   jTextArea2.append("");
   while(sc.hasNext()){
       String namex = jTextField5.getText();
       String phoneNox = jTextField6.getText();
       
       String name = sc.next();
       String phoneNo = sc.next();
       String email = sc.next();
       String streetAddress = sc.next();
       
       if(namex.equals(name)||phoneNox.equals(phoneNo)){
            String data = "Name: "+name+"\n "+"   PhoneNo: "+phoneNo+"\n "+"   Email: "+email+"\n "+"   StreetAddress: "+streetAddress+"\n\n";
            jTextArea2.append(data);   
       }  

   }
   sc.close();
}
catch(IOException e){
e.printStackTrace();

}
    }
```